# Combine Hibernate ResultTransformer result with original Hibernate Object

Tags: java, hibernate, hql, resulttransformer

Here is what I am trying to do:
1. Send an HQL to populate "User" Hibernate object.
2. Send a native SQL to retrieve a smaller dataset from a very large data column from "User" table.
3. Combine the mapped Hibernate object with the column result from step 2.

I read that ResultTransformer can be used to map the resultset from 2 to a Hibernate entity, which in my case the "User" entity. Is there a way to insert the results of the ResultTransformer mapping to my original User entity?

Here's some example:  1. HQL -  From User. We use Hibernate mapping file for User and using Bytecode Enhancement, we set    "xmlStringColumn lazy=true".     String hql = "FROM User";
         List users = session.createQuery(hql).list();   2. we send a query
     List resultXML = s.createSQLQuery(
  "XML SQL to get specific data")
  .setResultTransformer( Transformers.aliasToBean(User.class))
  .list();

User dto =(User) resultWithAliasedBean.get(0);       //Will need code to combine the User dto from the SQL to the original

Answer (score 0):

ResultTransformer bundles one to many relationship objects into single object.
For example,

Class A{

Set  b=new Hashset();

}

So if you start query from class A and add join on B it will end up in creating multipe objects of A.

ResultTransformer bundles data into single A object.

Can you please post code so we can understand what you are tyring to acheive!!!

Comment: Here's some example:

Comment: Here's some example:  1. HQL -  From User. We use Hibernate mapping file for User and using Bytecode Enhancement, we set    "xmlStringColumn lazy=true".     String hql = "FROM User";
         List<User> users = session.createQuery(hql).list();   2. we send a query                            
     List resultXML = s.createSQLQuery(
  "XML SQL to get specific data")
  .setResultTransformer( Transformers.aliasToBean(User.class))
  .list();

User dto =(User) resultWithAliasedBean.get(0);       //Will need code to combine the User dto from the SQL to the original

Comment: Check the select list names and property names of user are same

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. i just want to somehow set the 2nd query's result for the XML column (where only a couple of attributes returned) then put it in the same named XML column from initial HQL query result.